# Sum if values in other columns match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

| Amount | Reference1 | Reference2 | Sum of amounts with same reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100.00 | 1111 |  | 175 |
| 50.00 |  |  |  |
| 75.00 |  | 1111 | 175 |
| 110.00 |  | 2222 | 165 |
| 55.00 | 2222 |  | 165 |
| 78.00 |  |  |  |

I need to sum all amounts with same references, using a formula. Tried with SUMIF and SUMIFS, no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this it, worked for me using <kbd>IFS( )</kbd> & <kbd>SUMIFS()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=IFS(AND(B2="",C2=""),"",
       C2="",SUMIFS($A$2:$A$7,$C$2:$C$7,B2)+A2,
       B2="",SUMIFS($A$2:$A$7,$B$2:$B$7,C2)+A2)
```

---

Answer (score 2):

Well, this might suit you:

[image]

```
SUMIF(B2:B7,I2,A2:A7)+SUMIF(C2:C7,I2,A2:A7)
```

used two sumif, to pick up each indexing column.

Comment: Might be worth including a `-SUMIFS(A2:A7, B2:B7, I2, C2:C7, I2)`, so that you don't double-count if the same reference appears in both columns?

Comment: but for this I need to manually populate column I?

Comment: @IvantheSmurf did you try the way I have posted? It neither needs helper columns nor you have to create another auxiliary list of unique values?

Comment: So use something like: SORT(UNIQUE(B2:B7),,-1) in column I starting in cell I2 and then the results will still come out but for the largest first

Answer (score 1):

This should work, make a helper Column in Column E with `=IF(B2<>"",B2,IF(C2<>"",C2,-1))` and put this in Column D (Sum of amounts with same reference)

```
=SUMPRODUCT($A$2:$A$7,(($B$2:$B$7=E2)+($C$2:$C$7=E2)))
```